# CS8010: DLL recompile with dnSpy - agnostic assembly cannot have a processor specific module System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, .net-assembly, dnspy

I have a dll to edit Assembly Attributes
but when compile it notify error as my title.

How can I fix this?

I search on internet and find solution that open dll with dnspy32 or 64 and repeat edit, compile. It didn't work for me

Comment: As a wild guess, you have an assembly declared to be "Any CPU", but you are somehow including that module (i.e., that DLL) and it is processor-specific (say x64 or x86). How are you referencing that dll in your project. A solution (if it suites your needs) may be to declare the assembly to match that processor